# Machine Learning - Feature Selection or Dimensionality Reduction?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I am still exploring this area of Machine Learning and although I know what's the difference between Feature Selection and Dimensionality Reduction, I am finding some difficulties grasping the concepts of when to do Feature Selection or Dimensionality Reduction (or both together).

Assuming that I have a dataset with around 40 features, is it good practice to perform Dimensionality Reduction alone or Feature Selection alone? Or should there be a hybrid of both approaches (i.e. Do feature selection first and then dimensionality reduction - or vice versa)?

Answer (score 0):

The term *feature selection* is a bit misleading. It can have two meanings:

1. *Selecting* features by incorporating the domain knowledge (this involves constructing new features as well).

   For example, finding the rotation invariant points in an image data set or creating BMI as a new feature when you have height and weight as features.
2. *Keeping* only the features of high importance according to a some measure

   This is a one step of the dimensionality reduction process. The so-called dimensionality reduction process actually involves two steps:

   - Transforming the original features to new (artificial) features by changing the basis.

     eg. PCA does so by finding a set of orthogonal features so that the variance along each axis is maximized.
   - Keeping only the most important (importance is defined by some measure) features resulted in the above step. This is actually a feature selection step.

     eg. In PCA, this is achieved by keeping only the top-k number of features that have the highest explained variances.

---

As for the order of above (1) and (2) should happen: I think this is problem dependent.

If there's enough domain knowledge to construct/select features to cater the problem at hand, we should do the manual feature engineering (plus selection) first. If this feature engineering/selection process still results in a large number of features, then the so-called dimensionality reduction can be done to find a subspace that can represent the data with an even lesser number of totally new features that have almost no meaning in real life.

If the domain knowledge can't add anything to the data set, just doing dimensionality reduction would be fine which actually contain a *feature selection* step in it.

---

In a broad sense, we can think that feature selection is actually a special case of dimensionality reduction where no basis change occurs to the original data set.